# Multiple data sets in stored procedure in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dataset

I have a SP that returns four different result sets, but for it to be used in SSRS report i need to have it configured in a proper way.

```
USE LearnShare
GO

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.JH_LearnShare_ActiveUsers', N'P') IS NOT NULL 
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.JH_LearnShare_ActiveUsers
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.JH_LearnShare_ActiveUsers
        @enddate as date
    AS
    Begin
--Declare @enddate as date
--set @enddate = '6/30/2014'
    Select COUNT (distinct p.PersonID) as [Total Active Users] --50621
    FROM Enrollment E inner join 
    Person p on p.PersonID = e.[Person ID]
    WHERE p.active = 1
    and FirstLaunch between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
--DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) AND GETDATE()
    and [Completion Date] between  DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0))   AND @enddate
--and convert(varchar(10),[Enrollment Date] , 120) < convert(varchar(10),FirstLaunch , 120) --118669
--and FirstLaunch <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' -- this doesn't matter when adding [completion date] in where clause


    Select COUNT (distinct p.PersonID) as [Total Active Online Users] --49269
    FROM Enrollment E inner join 
    Person p on p.PersonID = e.[Person ID]
    left join class c
    on e.[resource id] = c.[resource id] 
    WHERE p.active = 1
    and FirstLaunch between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
--DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) AND GETDATE()
    and [Completion Date] between  DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
    and c.[Resource ID] is null 


    select COUNT (distinct p.personID) as [User with ILT courses] --22656
    from Person p 
    inner join Enrollment e on p.PersonID = e.[Person ID]
    inner join Resources r on e.[Resource ID] = r.[Resource ID]
    inner join Class c on r.[Resource ID] = c.[Resource ID]
    where p.Active = 1
    and c.[Class Date] between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
    and e.FirstLaunch between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
--DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)) AND GETDATE()
    and e.[Completion Date] between  DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate


    SELECT DateName(yyyy, FirstLaunch) EnrollmentYear, DATENAME(month, FirstLaunch) AS EnrollmentMonth , Count(distinct p.PersonID) as ActiveUsers --190312
    FROM Enrollment E inner join 
    Person p on p.PersonID = e.[Person ID]
    WHERE p.active = 1
    and FirstLaunch between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
    and [Completion Date] between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
--and convert(varchar(10),[Enrollment Date] , 120) < convert(varchar(10),FirstLaunch , 120) --118669
--and FirstLaunch <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' -- this doesn't matter when adding [completion date] in where clause 
    AND [Completion Date] <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY DateName(yyyy,FirstLaunch) , DATENAME(month,FirstLaunch), DATEPART(MONTH,FirstLaunch)
    ORDER BY DateName(yyyy,FirstLaunch) desc , DATEPART(MONTH,FirstLaunch) DESC

    End
```

I tried following

```
Create StoredProcedure sp_MultipleDataSets(@Param nvarchar(10))
as
begin
   if(@Param == "first")
      begin
         SELECT EMPID, ENAME, JOB, SAL, DEPTID FROM EMP -- first result set
      end
   if(@Param == "second")
      begin
        SELECT DEPTID, DNAME, LOC FROM DEPT --second result set
      end
end
```

Example adding if (@enddate == "first") begin select..... end but its giving me an error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure JH_LearnShare_ActiveUsers, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '='.

any help, please. Thanks!

Comment: WHy on earth are you trying to dothis? Write a proc that returns only teh selct you need for the report.

Comment: I need all four selects, because i need to show 4 different results in the report

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks! will keep that in mind from now on. I am very new to SQL writing stored procedure for the first time. Also if you could help me with the solution would be great.

Comment: The most common prefix I've seen is `usp_`. I'm also pretty sure the rdl can only read the first dataset, so if you need to use all 4 you're going to have to call the stored procedure 4 times.

Comment: how do i do that, I know i can add more parameters, but i don't know the exact format.

Comment: Just create 4 stored procedures, each returning only 1 result set. Then create 4 datasets in your report, one for each stored procedure.

Comment: TSQL also does not use `==` to test for equality which is why you are getting that error.  Switch those to a single equal sign like `IF @Param = 'First'`

Comment: instead of creating 4 stored procedures, can i pass the parameters that would return only one result set at a tiime. 
        PARAMETER datasets = '1,2,3,4'
    AS
    Begin
    if(@datasets == '1')
    begin
    Select COUNT (distinct p.PersonID) as [Total Active Users] 
    FROM Enrollment E inner join 
    Person p on p.PersonID = e.[Person ID]
    WHERE p.active = 1
    and FirstLaunch between DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@enddate), 0)) AND @enddate
    and [Completion Date] between  DATEADD(m,-11,DATEADD(mm, 
What is the right format/syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but maybe this response will help someone finding this later on.

You *could* write the SP in that way, however it seems unnecessarily complicated. There should be no reason you can't just write 4 different stored procedures. However, if you want to go down that route, that will work. EX:

```
IF @datasets = 1
begin
  select 1
end
IF @datasets = 2
begin
  select 2
end
```